# papervision 3d background

Tags: flash, 3d, papervision3d

anyone has an idea of how this kind of background is created?

http://www.papervision3d.org/

i'm going to create a flash game with 3d galaxies as the background. any ideas on how to achieve that? does the above link lead me the right direction?

thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no example here. give us another link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of background is called a [Sky Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29).

Here is a basic tutorial on how to create on in Papervision: http://blog.bennybottema.com/2009/05/22/easy-papervision3d-skybox-tutorial-and-source/